# Can I use the CLI to reset an IP address from a different subnet?

Tags: ip, command-line-interface, subnet, print-server, configuration

I'm working with a small office network which has fifteen devices on `192.168.2.x`. They want to add a print server to the network. Simple enough, except that the print server seems to think it's `192.168.23.8`. A firmware reset will change the print server IP to `192.168.1.10`--still on another subnet. I was unable get online drivers/manuals for further troubleshooting, but I'm having them shipped to me. In the meantime, I'm trying to see if I can fix the problem by manually configuring the device from the command line.

I can see the print server attached to my router, I know its MAC address and that it's thinking it's on a different subnet. I seem to recall that there's a way to get to that subnet because it's on the same router, but can't seem to do it. Is that plausible? or am I imagining something I learned in the past?

Comment: Uh, details like what OS your print server is running might help here...

Comment: none as far as I can tell. it's one of those cheap plug-n-play ones that attaches to your network via ethernet, has a USB port on the back, and is accessed via the web browser for firmware configuration. It's not nearly as sophisticated as a Server-based solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your computer IP address to one on the same subnet as the print server and you will then be able to access it.

```
192.168.23.XXX   - any number between 1-254 (but not 8)
```